# Blazor page Partial declarations of 'type' must not specify different base classes

Tags: c#, blazor

I have razor page with code behind

```
public partial class MyRazorPage: ComponentBase, IDisposable
{
   ...
}
```

I have several pages that have some common stuff, a lot of common stuff.

I created an abstract class like:

```
public abstract class MycustomComponentBase<TItem1, TItem2> : ComponentBase where TItem1: class, new() where TItem2: class, new()
{
  ...
}
```

and change razor class page to

```
public partial class MyRazorPage: MycustomComponentBase<MyClass1, MyClass2>, IDisposable
{
   ...
}
```

won't work because I get:

> Error CS0263  Partial declarations of 'MyRazorPage' must not specify different base classes   in MyRazorPage.razor.cs

I tried `public abstract partial class MycustomComponentBase<TItem1, TItem2>` as well but same error.

There's way to do that on partial class? I don't want to use `@inherits` because authentication and custom routing is working on actual implementation.

Comment: Just leave `MyRazorPage` alone in the partial part.

Comment: @Eldar and `MycustomComponentBase` ? what should do with that class ?

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you defined the partial type but it is generated by runtime.

Comment: Do you still have the old `MyRazorPage` definition in the project? That would explain it (2 different definitions to the same partial class).

Answer (score 3):

Your `MyRazorPage.razor` and `MyRazorPage.razor.cs` must inherit from the same class.  They both get compiled by the Razor compiler into a single class.  If you don't specify `@inherits` in the Razor file, the Razor compiler tries to use `ComponentBase` which contradicts the inheritance in the partial class.  Hence the error.

> I don't want to use @inherits because authentication and custom routing is working on actual implementation

Solve that problem.